# "custom intent URI" to send sms

Tags: android, xposed-framework

My goal is doing this kind of automation:

- if i press a certain combination of physical buttons, send an sms to a certain number with a certain text
- if i press another combination of physical buttons, send another pre-defined sms to a certain number
  etc...

Basically on my phone the only useful physical buttons are the volume_up and volume_down button.

After some researches, it seems the solution to do this automation is using xposed with the PBMC module.

I installed it and it seems it recognizes correctly the button press patterns, but i don't know how to send an sms.
It accepts a "custom intent URI", but don't know exactly what is it, can you explain me the syntax to send a pre-defined sms to a predefined number (if it's possible)?

If it's not possible doing it using xposed+PBMC, do you have other ideas on how to do so?